# Using data.table, conditional calculation w/o creating new column

Tags: r, data.table

I've looked through a number of previous posts but I haven't found a solution that works for my issue.
I have data.table that has these cols "id", "t1", "t2", and "days.to.followup". All the columns are numeric except id which is a character dtype, and "days.to.followup" is calculated column of t2 - t1.

```
ad.data[, days.to.followup := (t2-t1)]
```

I am trying to calculate the percent total, not as a column, just a stand alone value for rows where the value in t1 is greater than or equal to 365 versus the total number of observations in the data.table. I created a subset already to capture the conditional component, however, this was done because I am new to data.table so if there is a solution using chaining then that would be prefered:

```
at.least.yr <- ad.data[t1 >= 365]
```

As an FYI, the at.least.yr dt has 927,208 observations while the original ad.data dt has 1,561,265.

I tried the following, among other variations, but this returns 1 which is obviously incorrect:

```
ad.data[, .("Percent of Ppl with at least 1 yr" = 100*(length(at.least.yr)/length(ad.data)))]
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86MJu.png)

Comment: I added a pic of it

Comment: Please check the solution posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `length` of `at.least.yr` would give the number of columns as `at.least.yr` is still a data.table.  May be, the below should work

```
library(data.table)
ad.data[, .(Percent_of_Pple_with_at_least_1yr = 100 * mean(t1 >= 365))]
```

Comment: I need to calculate percent total of ppl with a t1 value of 365 or more in comparison to the total size of the data, so I don't need the mean value of t1 I am only using that as filter for the numerator in percent total calculation

Comment: @saddle_fish  If you check it is the mean of the logical expression and not the `mean` of 't1'

Comment: @saddle_fish  e.g. `v1 <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE); 100 * mean(v1)#[1] 40`

Comment: I see what you mean now, apologies!